# Convert Python(2.7) dictionary to valid query params

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, urllib, urlencode, urlparse

So I've been looking around quite a bit so far, and found hits but nothing that has quite fit this bill IMO. What I want to be able to do is take a Python dict called 'result' (note that 'keyword_scores' is a list of dicts, inside the 'data' dict.):

```
>>> print result
>>> {   
        u'data': {   
            u'clean_table': u'true',
            u'keyword_scores': [   
                {   
                    u'keyword': u'edited for easy reading on SO',
                    u'score': 0.4054651081081644
                }
            ],
            u'user_id': u'2'
        }
    }
```

and, at least I think, use some combination of

```
urllib.urlencode()
```

and

```
urlparse.parse_qs()
```

to be able to concatenate as 'query_string' onto a URL for use inside:

```
urllib2.Request(host_domain + some_post_data_endpoint + query_string)
```

I only suggest these libraries since thats what I think I need to use based on my searching so far, but I am wide open with approaches and tools to use here. The problem I'm having is, for whatever reason, it seems like I need to urlencode() it before I call parse_qs(), but other suggestions say I need to call parse_qs() first before encoding. Doesn't seem like there's a clean-cut way to convert a dictionary thats not completely "flat" into query parameters for urllib2.Request() to use.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you only want keyword_scores in the query string? Can you provide the example query string you would like in this example?

Comment: I think that's the problem right, I can't create a properly encoded query string for urllib2.Request() to handle since the data I want to send has lists/dicts inside the outer dict. Typing it out with all of the replacements wouldn't be very useful (unless I'm misunderstanding you).

Comment: Ok, was just trying to understand the problem. I've given it a shot and posted and answer below. I don't think you need parse_qs if what you want to do is pass the result dictionary to your endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some endpoint to which you want to post the data. Then you can just do the following and decode the url at the endpoint:

```
import urllib
result = {u'data': {u'clean_table': u'true',u'keyword_scores': [{u'keyword': u'edited for easy reading on SO', u'score': 0.4054651081081644}],u'user_id': u'2'}}
result_string = urllib.urlencode(result)
urllib2.Request(host_domain + some_post_data_endpoint + "?result=" + result_string)
```

For example, if your endpoint is JS, you can just do the following to get result as the same dictionary:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var result = JSON.parse(url.searchParams.get("result"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out: I kind of cheated and found the Python version of the full request in Postman, and saw how it was encoding the URL and worked towards replicating that. I'll post an explanation shortly...

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this was leverage Postman to find out how it was encoding the URL, while also switching to use the requests library instead of urllib2/urllib.

Something like:

```
raw_json = json.dumps(result)
encoded_json = urllib.quote(raw_json)
tmp = Template("data=$d")
# request will look like encoded nonsense like "data=%7B%22clean_table%22%3A%20true%2C%20%22keyword_scores%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22score%22%3A%200.4054651081081644%2C%20%22keyword%22%3A%20%22bruins%22%7D%5D%2C%20%22user_id%22%3A%20%222%22%7D"
request = tmp.substitute(d=encoded_json)
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=request, headers=headers)
```

NOTE: The headers parameter was required.